# Переключение страниц при парсинге

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3

from urllib3 import proxy_from_url

url = "https://www.sulpak.kz/f/smartfoniy"
base_url = "https://www.sulpak.kz"
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
container = soup.select_one("ul.goods-container")


products = container.find_all("li", class_="tile-container")

urls = []

for product in products :
    url = product.select_one('div.goods-photo a')['href']
    urls.append(base_url + url)

args = []

for url in urls :
    response = requests.get(url)    
    html = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    name = soup.select_one("h1").text
    price = soup.select_one("span.sum").text
    args.append((name, price))
   

conn = sqlite3.connect("mydata.db")

cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM phones"

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO phones VALUES (?,?)", args)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Вот код, он берет одну страницу сайта, парсит товары там и заносит в базу данных, мне нужно чтоб он переходил на следующие страницы

Answer (score 0):

Если вы перейдете на следующую страницу, вы заметите что к адресу сайта добавляется `?page=2`. То есть это можно реализоваться с помощью цикла. Как это происходит:
вы смотрите сколько в общем страниц и пишете цикл for

```
base_url = "https://www.sulpak.kz/f/smartfoniy"
current_url = None
for page in range(1,15):
    current_url = base_url + f"?page={page}"
```

И в каждом цикле парсите current_url

Comment: что-то не получается,  добавил цикл for page in range(1,15) и в остальные циклы строки current_url = base_url + f"?page={page}", но все равно парсит одну страницу

Comment: @ДанилРумянцев вы наверное добавили цикл, но весь остальной код оставили без изменений. А смысл в том чтобы вызывать парсинг к теле цикла, а не за его пределами. Я вам предлагаю заключить весь свой предыдущий код в функцию и в качестве аргумента передавать current_url и вызывать эту функцию в цикле for

Comment: Можете в мой код это внедрить, а то я Питон особо не знаю и как что не совсем понятно